# Migrating application from VCL to FMX in Delphi

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

I'm migrating my application from Delphi VCL Application to FMX and I'm stuck in this piece of code where I should drag `Image1` beyond the edges of the Form, but the same code doesn't have the same effect on the FMX form. How could I adapt this code to Firemonkey.

I tried to use the same code that I already use in VCL but the image does not move beyond the edges of the form as it does in my previous application.

This is the code I use in VCL and what I'm trying to adapt in FMX

```
procedure Tfrmmain.Image1MouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
  Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Single);
begin
  if ssLeft in Shift then
  begin
    CanDragging:= True;
    StartDragPos:= ClientToScreen(PointF(X, Y));
  end;
end;

procedure Tfrmmain.Image1MouseMove(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState; X,
  Y: Single);
begin
  if CanDragging then
  begin
    Image1.Position.Point:= ScreenToClient(ClientToScreen(
    Image1.Position.Point + ClientToScreen(PointF(X, Y)) - StartDragPos));
  end;
end;

procedure Tfrmmain.Image1MouseUp(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
  Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Single);
begin
  CanDragging:= False;
end;

procedure Tfrmmain.MouseUpEvent(X, Y: Integer);
begin
  CanDragging:= False;
  StartDragPos:= Point(0, 0);
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm very new to Firemonkey and some things might go unnoticed. Soon after posting this question I decided to continue my research and found this question that seems to solve my problem. So little for a huge resolution for me.

Here is the solution I will use

[AutoCapture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42481039/fmx-how-can-i-get-a-forms-mousemove-events-outside-of-the-form)